# Angular2 RC7 Http module error loading

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have an Angular2 test application that was written in RC4 that worked fine.  I'm now trying to upgrade it to RC7 and I'm getting the following error message

```
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    Evaluating http://localhost:7864/traceur
    Error loading http://localhost:7864/traceur
    Error loading http://localhost:7864/libs/@angular/http/index.js as "@angular/http" from http://localhost:7864/app/recentActivity/recentActivity.module.js
```

My recentActivity.module looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { RecentActivityService } from './recentActivity.service';
import { RecentActivityComponent } from './recentActivity.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, HttpModule],
    declarations: [RecentActivityComponent],
    exports: [RecentActivityComponent],
    providers: [RecentActivityService]
})
export class RecentActivityModule {
}
```

I can't figure out what the problem is here.  If I look in the network traffic I can see that is download @angular/http/index.js with a 200 status and the downloaded file is the expected results.  So I don't know why it is saying that there is an error loading it.  Where else do I need to look.

systemjs.config is below

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function () {
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    var map = {
        'app': 'app', // 'dist',
        '@angular': 'libs/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'libs/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs': 'libs/rxjs'
    };
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    var packages = {
        'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
    };
    var ngPackageNames = [
      'common',
      'compiler',
      'core',
      'forms',
      'http',
      'platform-browser',
      'platform-browser-dynamic',
      'router',
      'router-deprecated',
      'upgrade'
    ];

    var ngIndexPackageNames = [
   'http'
    ];
    // Individual files (~300 requests):
    function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
    // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
    var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
    // Add package entries for angular packages
    ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
    ngIndexPackageNames.forEach(packIndex);
    var config = {
        //meta: {
        //    '*.js': {
        //        scriptLoad:true
        //    }
        //},
        map: map,
        packages: packages
    };
    System.config(config);
})(this);
```

Comment: Please share your system.config.js

Comment: Updated question above

Comment: Compare it with https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-typescript-systemjs/blob/master/systemjs.config.js See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html and this https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1

Comment: I figured it out.  Feel free to submit as an answer yurzui, since you pointed it out to me.  I had put this in because of some issue I had previously 
var ngIndexPackageNames = [
   'http'
    ];
Which I just removed and all is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the release of **RC.6** angular2 team announced new breaking changes of packages configuration

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1

> npm packages: code in ESM (ES6 Modules) format is now published at the
>   default location in the npm package with package.json's main entry
>   pointing to an UMD bundle (primarily for node, and webpack 1 users).
>
> If you are using SystemJS to load Angular, you should adjust your
>   SystemJS configuration to point to the UMD bundles (present in the npm
>   package).
>
> Please see this example [SystemJS config](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/3b7452cc444c49c139ea39523ced0468c2362c16/systemjs.config.js#L17-L34).